# What is the best way to connect R with IB?

Tags: programming, interactive-brokers

I am looking to connect my trading models to trade in IB. my models are R based.
what is the best (and fastest) way to create a system that get data from IB and based on this data create trades in IB.
I looked everywhere and the only thing that i found that might be helpful is the IBrokers package but it is possible only to get data and not to place orders.
I know that IB API use mainly java but I am not familiar with java so I prefer to do everything in R if this is possible.
Thanks,

Comment: > I am looking to connect my trading models to trade in IB. my models are R based. what is the best (and fastest) way to create a system that get data from IB I try to solve the same problem. I have posted some of my code here - [https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/how-can-i-export-intraday-stock-data-into-csv-from-interactive-broker-or-yahoo-f](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/how-can-i-export-intraday-stock-data-into-csv-from-interactive-broker-or-yahoo-f)

Answer (score 1):

[IBrokers](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=IBrokers) does support orders: see `?twsOrder` and `?placeOrder`.