# How can I export intraday stock data into CSV from Interactive Broker or Yahoo Finance?

Tags: programming, historical-data, interactive-brokers, intraday, yahoofinance

Google Finance API seems to be down forever.

Are there instructions or manuals for downloading intraday stock data into CSV files from Interactive Broker OR Yahoo Finance?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say intraday, what particular granularity of data are you looking for? just the daily OHLCV? or minute by minute, ect...

Comment: Minute by minute, or hourly, ... etc and preferably with OHLCV

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I currently do not know of any free data providers who will give you granularity beyond just daily data. As for Interactive Brokers, they do have historical data services but you have to have an account with them and pay a monthly or yearly rate for the data subscriptions.